# How to fix MySQL.Connection.Open() error in release version of a UWP app?

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp, database-connection

I'm creating a daycare app and have been struggling with the release version of the build(everything works fine in debug).

I have a combobox that gets populated from a MySql db but for some reason the app crashes on Connection.Open();

Here is the Combobox's code

```
        void FillComboBox()
    {

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectString))
        {

            try
            {
                MySqlCommand da = new MySqlCommand("select childName,username from Todlers;", conn);

                da.Connection = conn;
                da.Connection.Open();

                MySqlDataReader drd = da.ExecuteReader();
                Children child = new Children(UserName,ChildName);

                    while (drd.Read())
                    {
                        childCombo.Items.Add(drd["ChildName"].ToString());
                    }

                child.UserName = drd["UserName"].ToString();

                drd.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Write(ex);

            }
        }
    }
```

The app seems to work fine but the Combobox doesn't get populated
I know the connectionstring and overall connection is fine since you need it to log into the app in the first place

Comment: Could you get the exception message to display and then paste it here? Without it it is hard to help

Comment: Also, in case your MySQL server is local, the problem might be related to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/278579/uwp-app-dont-connect-to-local-mysql-server-after-r.html - you need to enable local loopback

Comment: @MartinZikmund its remote not local

Comment: Then definitely try to get the exception message displayed, so that we know what is happening :-)

Comment: @MartinZikmund I have the log but it's too long to post here and im not sure what is important

Comment: Definitely at least the message and part of the stack trace. Anything helps :-)

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in MySql.Data.dll  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.IsReplicationGroup(String groupName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open$catch$0()
   at SQL_Connection_Test.Admin.FillComboBox() in C:\Admin.xaml.cs:line 74

Comment: Your MySQL library may not be compatible with UWP projects. Try uninstalling MySql.Data, then installing this package from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that .NET Native compiler throws away some types, that are activated by reflection in `MySql.Data` library. Please go to the `Default.rd.xml` file in the **Properties** folder of your UWP app and add the following inside the `<Application>` tag:

```
<Namespace Name="MySql.Data" Dynamic="Required All" />
```

Then rebuild and see if it helps